# How do I give the asterisk as a command-line argument in Linux?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am taking command-line arguments in the code below.

The trouble is that if I run this code on Linux, `*` is a glob that refers to all of the files in the directory (I know because I printed the arguments and it printed a list of my files), which causes my code to not do multiplication. All other operations work fine.

I have tried preceding the `*` with a `\` like so: `\*`

I have also tried passing it in quotes like so: `'*'`

However, none of these approaches cause my code to do multiplication.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a, b, result;
    char opr;

    if(argc!=4)
    {
        printf("Invalid arguments...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[3]);
    opr=argv[2][0];
    switch(opr)
    {
        case '+':
            result=a+b;
            break;
        case '-':
            result=a-b;
            break;
        case '*':
            result=a*b;
            break;
        default:
            result=0;
            break;
    }
    if(opr=='+' || opr=='-' || opr=='*')
        printf("Result: %d %c %d = %d\n",a,opr,b,result);
    else
        printf("Undefined Operator...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

How do I pass an asterisk as an argument to my application?

Comment: try giving it in single quotes '' as special characters lose their special meaning inside single quotes.

Comment: @yabhishek In standard Unix shells, `*` loses its special meaning inside double quotes, too.

Comment: `\*` or `'*'` should work.  If they don't the problem is probably missing spaces between the 3 arguments your program requires...

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact command line you're using?

Comment: Are you telling us, that giving `'*'` as command line arguments (with those quotes) still lists all files on the directory, instead of passing a plain `*` to the program? I don't believe you. If you are sure, what shell are you using?

Comment: As others have noted, the backslash `\*` or quotes `'*'` or `"*"` should work. And in fact your program can multiply just fine for me, using any of those techniques, so your problem must be somewhere else, in something you're not showing us.

Comment: @SteveSummit This code didn't even compile before my edit, so how could it have worked for you?

Comment: @JL2210 Well, I had to fix the `opr` references, of course, but that was too trivial to mention.  (Clearly not the real problem, which we're all still clueless on.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both quoting with `''` (single quotes) or `""` (double quotes) or escaping it with a preceding `\`  should work. You can test it like this:

```
$ echo *
bar foo
$ echo '*'
*
$ echo "*"
*
$ echo \*
*
```

The shell does not expand it in the latter two cases. Double-quotes will suffice, too, but can cause problems around some other characters.  Single quotes are safer.

You can also run your program with `strace` to check the argument vector given:

```
$ strace echo "*"
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "*"], 0x7ffc26311518 /* 24 vars */) = 0
```

Comment: Running it in a directory with no files will also work.

Comment: @JL2210 Hehe, that's correct ;) Good idea ;)

Comment: Thank you. I must have made some mistake earlier cuz it seems to be working now.